# Regular expression for decimal “X.X”

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to figure out the regular expression for “X.X”, where ‘X’s are numbers.

Some valid values:

- `1.1`
- `2.0`
- `0.1`
- `9.1`
- `9.9`

Some invalid values:

- `10.1`
- `9.22`
- `1`
- `10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your examples this regex should work:

```
/^\d\.\d$/
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/vdemgjS9NY

Comment: It’s safer in general to use a regex testing tool for the regex flavor of your particular language. There’s a list of such tools on [the regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Here’s a [live demo in RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=^\d\.\d%24&input=1.1%0A2.0%0A0.1%0A9.1%0A9.9%0A10.1%0A9.22%0A1%0A10), which uses JavaScript’s regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex expert,
but "^\d.\d$"
seems to work for me when I test on Rubular for a line with only X.X and nothing more.